# how to use GPS traffic data existing in MSSQL format, on toQGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql-server, qgis-processing

I have GPS traffic data in MSSQL format, consisting of `ID, LAT, LONG, SPEED, DIRECTION,TRACK TIME`.

How do I use this in QGIS? I tried with MYSQL, but connecting to server was an issue.

As my data is not spatial and does not have any geometry information I cannot use SpatiaLite either.

Comment: you could always export the data to .csv and then add as delimited text layer without geometry.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the built in MSSQL provider in QGIS to load a table with non-spatial data. Just make sure to check "Also list tables with no geometry" when you set up the MSSQL connection.

Then you can try using the tool "Points layer from table" in the geoprocessing toolbox to create points from the LAT/LONG columns.

I can read non-spatial tables from MSSQL with QGIS 2.18 without issues.

You could also export your data into a csv file and import that as a points layer.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for your time... I tried doing it, as my data is huge QGIS(Am using 2.6.1) gets crashed when I try to operate.

Comment: Then I would recommend 1) If possible, upgrade to the latest version of QGIS since it's more optimised, 2) Export the data as CSV and import it as points (turn off rendering as well while doing this so QGIS doesn't have to render all the points) and then 3) Export the resulting points layer as Spatialite or Geopackage with a spatial index. That should make it workable.